# Position of Gameobject Changes When Hit Play Button

Tags: unity, collider

I have a 3D Humanoid model. When I press play button, suddenly position of model  changes and collider doesn't match with model.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to two things,
Animation
Start() Method

**Animation:**
You have an animation that offsets the character in the start.
Try disabling animation/animator component on your player.

**Start Method:**
There is a script on your player that offsets the player in the start. Try disabling any scripts on your player and see if it works.

Noting the collider you have attached to the gameobject that doesn't move, it could be that a child of the main object is the one being moved. Parent is the one with the collider.
If these solutions don't work, I think you will need to provide a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this may solve it, but try changing Update mode to Normal
if it doesn't solve it try to desactivate Animator tab. if the latest solves your problems, that means that you should probably play with options in your currently used animations properties. That's all i can think of :)

Comment: I tried your first solution and didn't work. But I couldn't understand second solution. How can I descative Animator tab and How is it gonna help about colliders ? Thanks for your help

Comment: I meant the Animator component. you see in the first image at the left of "Animator" uncheck it and observe if the problem still happens

Comment: sometimes animations are well made and you need to check/uncheck some parameters so that the animation doesn't go out of your character position. To make it simple, you can think of them not centering the animation character when making them.

Comment: Nothing happened. Thanks for comment